# django + Angularjs некорректные данные и форма не валидируется

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

Использую django + angularjs. Отправляются некорректные данные и форма не валидируется. Вюха на базе `CreateView`. Переопределил методы `form_valid` и `form_invalid` чтобы понять в чем причина и просто делаю в них `print self.request.POST`.

Как форму отправить через `ajax` чтобы django смог их корректно прочитать?

сейчас данные приходят в виде

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"email":"blabla@gmail.com","number":456,"name":"Austria","text":"sdgdfhyju"}': [u'']}>
```

а должны

```
<QueryDict: {u'text': [u'qwerty'], u'email': [u'some@site.com'], u'name': [u'Austria'], u'number': [u'9999']}>
```

фрагменты кода:

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto">
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="processForm()">

        <p>
            <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
            <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email">
            <span ng-show="errorEmail">{{errorEmail}}</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="id_number">Number:</label>
            <input id="id_number" name="number" type="number" ng-model="user.number">
            <span ng-show="errorNumber">{{errorNumber}}</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
            <input id="id_name" maxlength="120" name="name" type="text" ng-model="user.name">
            <span ng-show="errorName">{{errorName}}</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="id_text">Text:</label>
            <textarea cols="40" id="id_text" maxlength="1000" name="text" rows="10" ng-model="user.text"></textarea>
            <span ng-show="errorText">{{errorText}}</span>
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </div>




// angularjs

$scope.user = {};
$scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
        method  : 'post',
        url     : '/some/',
        data    : $scope.user, // в jquery всегда делал $(this).serialize() и проблем не было
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
    .success(function(data) {            
        console.log(data);
        if (data.errors) {
            console.log('errors');
            $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
            $scope.errorNumber = data.errors.number;
            $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
            $scope.errorText = data.errors.text;
        } else {
            console.log('blablabla');
        }
    });
  };
 }]);
```

Comment: Если вы ответили на свой вопрос сами, пожалуйста оформите его как ответ к данному вопросу отдельным ответом. Спасибо.

Comment: либо убрать `headers` и отправлять как json

Answer (score 1):

оказалось что всего лишь нужно `$httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.user)`